# Robocopy options in windows 8.1

Tags: robocopy

I am trying to copy 1TB of data. I want to copy everything possible, what kind of Robocopy options are recommended in this case? I use:

```
/E = copy all all subdirectories including empty
/dcopy:T = copy folder timestamps
/B = backup mode <-- no sure what this does
/J =  what does this do <-- no idea what this does
/r:10 = retry 10 times on failed files
/unicode = show status as unicode
/tee = write output to console also
/log:path = save log file to
/np = do not fill the output with useless percentages
```

Is there any option I am missing?

No sure what `/J` does. Backup just bypasses permissions? Also, what

```
U Auditing information
```

Is?

Comment: All arguments are well documented.  If you don't know what an argument does you should look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I donT find a /J option in the docs?  Do you mean "jobs"?

You can find out what auditing info is here: http://knowledgebase.solarwinds.com/kb/questions/3454/How+to+enable+file+auditing+in+Windows

We would have trouble recommending options to you.  For example, usage of /mir depends on whether you want to remove files at the destination or not (?).  Remember, if a file gets deleted at the source, you may or may not want that file to be purged on the destination.  The options you end up using need to fit what you want.  We donT know that.

Comment: /J means copy using unbuffered I/O (recommended for large files).